# The 'file' scheme is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, visual-studio

When I run with the below Dockerfile my.net API is exposing only in port 80 and shows "The 'file' scheme is not supported" whereas when I run this docker file through VisualStudio it exposes to 443 and works like a charm

[image]

Here is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend/RECashMachineBackend.csproj", "RECashMachineBackend/"]
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend.Repository/RECashMachineBackend.Repository.csproj", "RECashMachineBackend.Repository/"]
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend.Models/RECashMachineBackend.Models.csproj", "RECashMachineBackend.Models/"]
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend/nuget.config", ""]
# COPY ["*.props", "./"]

# ARG PAT=localhost
# RUN sed -i "s|</configuration>|<packageSourceCredentials><Techdome.Identity><add key=\"Username\" value=\"PAT\" /><add key=\"ClearTextPassword\" value=\"${PAT}\" /></Techdome.Identity></packageSourceCredentials></configuration>|" nuget.config

RUN dotnet restore "RECashMachineBackend/RECashMachineBackend.csproj" --configfile "./nuget.config"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RECashMachineBackend"
RUN dotnet build "RECashMachineBackend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RECashMachineBackend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RECashMachineBackend.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Dockerfile, as shown, I'd only expect your app to be reachable on port 80.

That's because the aspnet image that you base your final image on, sets the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to `http://+:80`.

Having `EXPOSE 443` doesn't change that. EXPOSE is only documentation.

If you want your app to listen on port 443 as well, you should change the value of ASPNETCORE_URLS. I suspect that Visual Studio does that when it runs the container. You can do it by setting the variable in your Dockerfile, like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:80;https://+:443"
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend/RECashMachineBackend.csproj", "RECashMachineBackend/"]
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend.Repository/RECashMachineBackend.Repository.csproj", "RECashMachineBackend.Repository/"]
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend.Models/RECashMachineBackend.Models.csproj", "RECashMachineBackend.Models/"]
COPY ["RECashMachineBackend/nuget.config", ""]
# COPY ["*.props", "./"]

# ARG PAT=localhost
# RUN sed -i "s|</configuration>|<packageSourceCredentials><Techdome.Identity><add key=\"Username\" value=\"PAT\" /><add key=\"ClearTextPassword\" value=\"${PAT}\" /></Techdome.Identity></packageSourceCredentials></configuration>|" nuget.config

RUN dotnet restore "RECashMachineBackend/RECashMachineBackend.csproj" --configfile "./nuget.config"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RECashMachineBackend"
RUN dotnet build "RECashMachineBackend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RECashMachineBackend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RECashMachineBackend.dll"]
```

That will make your app listen on port 443 as well. But I think you're still missing copying a certificate into your dockerfile to use, when communicating over HTTPS.

Comment: How do give that HTTPS certificate into docker any idea?

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-6.0